# Partial Derivative of a Scalar-product Resulting from Vector Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations

I am trying to differentiate the function below, but I am running into problems due to the point-wise multiplication with the matrix.

$f(x,y,A) = (x^{T}y) \cdot A$

Where $\cdot$ denotes point-wise multiplication and $x \in R^n$, $y \in R^n$, $A \in R^{m \times k}$ and I am trying to find the element-wise derivative with respect to $x$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.